# No audio on Lenovo Think Pad 11e with 20.04

Tags: sound, lenovo, 20.04

I have just installed Ubuntu 20.04 on a Think Pad 11e previously running Chrome OS. Everything seems to be running fine except for there is no audio from the speakers or head phones. I have tried the fixes mentioned here:

https://itsfoss.com/fix-sound-ubuntu-1304-quick-tip/

and I think I have done them correctly but as I am very new there is the possibility I have messed them up somehow. The output device is Dummy Audio (whatever that is?) and there is no option to change it. I would be extremely grateful for any help and advice you may be able to give.
EDIT: The audio is working through HDMI when I connect it to the TV

Comment: Still having issues sadly. I wonder if I should maybe use an older version of Ubuntu? Any thoughts. Thanks Matt

Answer (score 0):

You should try installing private drivers in 
[Software & Updates](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sLiCI.png).

Check this: https://itsfoss.com/install-additional-drivers-ubuntu/

Comment: Hi and thank you for taking the time to reply to me. Unfortunately there is no option to install any additional drivers.